# Can't understand connection pooling error using JPA, Tomcat, Oracle

Tags: tomcat, jpa, oracle10g, connection-pooling

I have the following code in `context.xml` for Tomcat:

```
<Resource name="ds/OracleDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="1" maxIdle="2" maxWait="2"
username="demo" password="demo"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
```

I have this code in `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
 <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
 <res-ref-name>ds/OracleDS</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I have written code in `persistence.xml` like:

```
<persistence-unit name="ReceivablesPU"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:ds/OracleDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

I don't understand `java:ds/OracleDS`,`<Resource name="ds/OracleDS"`,`<res-ref-name>ds/OracleDS</res-ref-name>`. The error is:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-7060] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0 (Build b40-rc (03/21/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:ds/OracleDS].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed through a java: URL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changes in contex.xml:

```
<Resource name="OracleDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="1" maxIdle="2" maxWait="2"
    username="demo" password="demo"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
```

i changes in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
     <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
     <res-ref-name>OracleDS</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

i changes in persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="ReceivablesPU"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/OracleDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

then i got the output....

Answer (score 2):

In `persistence.xml`, your third line should look like this:

```
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/ds/OracleDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer to a similar (but not duplicate question):

[Jetty Data Source, Hibernate, datasource not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714899/jetty-data-source-hibernate-datasource-not-found/7715096#7715096)

Depending on Java EE Web App container, for a data source named "ds/OracleDS" you may need to prefix its JNDI context with "java:comp/env" when addressing it (like , in your persistence.xml file) to make it work.

In your particular case of Tomcat, I'd try the following:

```
<Resource name="ds/OracleDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="1" maxIdle="2" maxWait="2"
username="demo" password="demo"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
```

You don't really need anything in your web.xml. The above configuration in context.xml will make Tomcat expose the data source as a JNDI resource

Finally, in persistence.xml put:

```
<persistence-unit name="ReceivablesPU"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/ds/OracleDS</non-jta-data-source>
```